# Runfile at spyder instead of result of my code

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, conda

every time i run any code this comes to me 
i want a way to just see my code result not telling me the path of running my file The error
[image: The error]

Comment: Which code are you running? Can you give more detail about your problem. The negative score means **urgent attention** is needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Any code
For example 5+5
Or importing library
Or print()
Any code at all

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is not an error, `runfile` is the command used by Spyder to run your file in one of its consoles. Without it is not possible to execute files, so it's not possible to get rid of it.

Comment: You need to use a `print` statement somewhere to get your results printed in the console. For instance `print(1 + 1)`.